# How to find profit or loss percentage from consecutive rows

Tags: python, percentage, rowwise

I need a help in calculating profit/loss percentage. I have a data frame as follows

```
Date         Price    
2017-5-20    50    
2017-5-20    60
2017-5-20    45
```

I need a new column in dataframe which calculates profit or loss percentage of consecutive rows, such as

```
Date         Price    Prof/Loss
2017-5-20    50       0
2017-5-20    60       16.66
2017-5-20    45      -23.07
```

Comment: How did you get the `-23.07`? and what have you tried?

Comment: I guess you meant `df['Prof/Loss'] = [0, 16.66, -23.07]` haha :P

Comment: its just (45-60)/100

Comment: Yes. I am unable to execute it. Can u pl help on it

Comment: @PranayDishan How can you ask a question when you don't know what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = ['2017-05-20', '2017-05-20', '2017-05-20']
df['Price'] = [50, 60, 45]
df['Prof/Loss'] = (df['Price'] / df['Price'].shift())*100 - 100
```

First, I think your math for calculating the Loss/Profit was wrong, I hope I fixed that for you.

Second, you can use the [.shift()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method to get the previous row, use .shift(-1) to get the next row.

Comment: Thank u so much dustin-we. It worked to my actual work that I am doing. And yes my calculation was wrong, thank u correcting me.

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to mark your question as solved :)